# How to get element text/value/innertext using Nightwatch?

Tags: json, node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I have 10 elements with the same class ('botaoParametroAc') and I would like to check one by one and use a click on element that contains "id" as text. This is my code right now:

```
browser
    .waitForElementVisible('#txtBusca', 4000)
    .elements('class name', 'botaoParametroAc', function(res) {
      for(var item in res.value){
        console.log(item.text)
      }
    });
```

It is returning "undefined" for each item.

When I try to print res.value, it is the result:

> {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-2"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-3"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-4"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-5"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-6"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-7"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-8"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-9"}
>   {"ELEMENT":"0.06577812833436414-10"}

How can I get the text or attributes of each element?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update, it is working right now. I needed to get the elementIdAttribute for each element getting innerText to discover it and click on it when condition matches.

```
        browser
        .waitForElementVisible('#txtBusca', 4000)
        .elements('class name', 'botaoParametroAc', function(result) {
            result.value.map(function(element, err) {
                browser.elementIdAttribute(element.ELEMENT, 'innerText', function(res) {
                    if (res.value == 'id') {
                        browser.elementIdClick(element.ELEMENT);
                    }
                })
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, using elements + elementIdAttribute wasn't working well.

What I did instead was use execute():

```
'Verify table summary': function (browser) {
    browser.execute(function (data) {
      var innerTotal = 0;
      document.querySelectorAll('.cell-with-number')
         .forEach(a => innerTotal += Number(a.innerText));
      return innerTotal;
    }, [], function(res) {
      total = res.value;
    });
```

The var `total` will have the value returned from the script run in the contex of the browser.

Comment: I'm wondering, are you using the geckodriver and testing on firefox? I can't seem to get the "browser.elementIdAttribute(elements.value[iteration].ELEMENT)" to work for me.

Comment: This was some time ago, but since i wrote "For me, using elements + elementIdAttribute wasn't working well." I can only assume I didnt use elementIdAttribute neither, hence my workaround :-)

Answer (score 0):

As of the current nightwatch version (1.7.6) it seems like the simplest way to do this in a way that is compatible with both Chromedriver and Geckodriver is with [getElementProperty](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/getElementProperty.html#apimethod-page):

```
browser.getElementProperty('#thisElementId .some-class-name', 'innerText', 
  function(result) {
    console.log('result', result);
  }
);
```